# Polyharmonic system

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations, maximum-principle

In the problem, with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth bounded domain, and the given functions $h_1, h_2 \in C(\partial\Omega)$
\begin{equation}\nonumber%\label{eq:Pe}\tag{$P_{\varepsilon}$}
\left\{
 \begin{array}[c]{ll}
-\Delta \chi + \Delta^2 \chi = 0, & \text{in } \Omega, \\
 \chi = h_1, \; \Delta \chi = h_2, & \text{on } \partial\Omega\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
which admits a unique and regular solution $\chi \in H^2(\Omega)$, my question is, what can I say about
$$\|\chi\|_\infty $$

and $$\|\Delta\chi\|_\infty$$

Exists some bound involving $h_1$ or $h_2$?

Thanks for any help!